# How should I update FreePBX version 2.0.X to 14?

Tags: asterisk, voip, freepbx

I am working on a project and the client is using freePBX version 2.0.X and they want to upgrade their version to 14.0.X. How should I do this keeping in mind that all the data and configurations needs to be migrated to the newer version?

**edit: to those who are marking it negative, I am new to this and if I new the answer then, I wouldn't ask.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have update 2.0->2.2. After that 2.2 -> 2.4, 2.4->2.5, 2.5->2.6

After that you have updat 2.6 to 13, 13 to 14.

Some of this upgrades not go without problem, huge experience required.

On upgrade from 2.6 to 13 you have also upgrade asterisk to version 13.

If you have no very complex config, in most cases faster will be backup extensions, dids, restore, put all other config items.

ps also you need have archive for thoose version,i think it will be complex to find something below 2.4